# Is it normal to lose 30 minutes of data on a SQL Server crash?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, database-replication

We have worked with Oracle for a number of years and we now need to develop a new application using SQL Server in AWS for the first time.

What surprised us, is that the new SQL Server DBA told us off the bat that SQL Server uses some kind of replication every 30 minutes (or with 30 minutes delay, I don't remember): in short, he said that on an AWS SQL Server crash, when the secondary server comes up "we will lose *only* 30 minutes of data in Production".

**EDIT**: By "crash", we mean the primary server is dead/unrecoverable.

We never expected this as a normal behavior and we haven't seen something like this in Oracle... ever.

Is it normal to expect to lose 30 minutes of **commits** on a SQL Server crash? This would include payments, invoices, and other transactions that we would consider quite important.

Should I push back about this, or this is considered normal in SQL Server?

Comment: May be it is about SQL Server on AWS. In on-premises SQL Server you can set up recovery model to FULL and perform log-backups as frequent as you need to minimize possible data loss or implement some HADR-solution

Comment: That's probably a matter for your RTO and RPO policy makers to debate. SQL Server transaction log backups can certainly be scheduled and moved off-server much more frequently than every 30 minutes.

Comment: Depends what you mean by a "crash". If you just mean that the service or host crashed, the host/service did not terminate "gracefully", but the device isn't "dead" then you would at most "lose" what ever data hasn't been committed yet. If you mean that the entire host failed, you would lose what ever wasn't captured in your prior backup (assuming your stored these elsewhere); that isn't unique to SQL Server, Oracle has that too.

Comment: Not normal in general. SQL Server has things like Always On availability groups which should keep secondaries updated either synchronously or with much lesser lag than described in the Q. Does AWS offer this?

Comment: @Larnu I edited the question. By crash we mean a dead primary server, and we are concerned only about committed transactions.

Comment: @MartinSmith As a general advise, would you recommend that I push back on this to make the delay smaller? I don't know if I will succeed, but does it make sense at least to ask for it?

Comment: We need specifics on the AWS implementation but it is not normal to lose any committed transactions in a SQL Server HA configuration. Perhaps your DBA means a DR scenario, where there are trade-offs between RPO and performance.

Comment: I do not use SQLServer, but [AWS describes using it in a multi-AZ deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerMultiAZ.html) (which is different from setting up read replicas and promoting one), so I think your DBA is either incorrect or you misinterpreted what they said. I would ask for clarification after reading that page, and hire a new DBA if necessary.

Comment: "AWS SQL Server" is insufficient to describe the setup. Is this RDS or SQL built on EC2? In either case, has any sort of SQL-native HA been set up (in which case RPO is typically measured in seconds as there is another server constantly receiving committed transactions)? As others have stated, this is also informed by tran log backup frequency (which is configurable). TL;DR - yes, you can push back (or at least ask for specifics).

Comment: I'd push back and gather more information on the details what your DBA means. In case you use AWS RDS with Multi-AZ setup, changes to the primary instance are synchronously replicated to the standby instance, which means that data committed to the primary is also available on the secondary. See https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/ for details.

Comment: SQL Server Cluster on AWS Cloud would save data. (hot-hot), log backup for DR

Comment: Perhaps better asked on sister site,  https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if that's you pay for or have setup.

For Oracle, I'm pretty sure that that you did not ask.  Clients always assume RTO and RPO are 0.  When you explain what RTO and RPO, they request 0 for RTO and PRO. Then when you explain the complexity and cost, the client is likely okay okay with 24 hours while we do our best for our default 15 minutes.  Take a look at

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/sql-server-architecture-review/

I love Brent's response for one of the questions:

"For Infrastructure-as-a-Service, there are no changes. For Platform-as-a-Service, there’s no chart – just put in your credit card and turn the knob to the level of protection that you want. "

So, what's in your wallet?

Here is one definition of RTO and RPO, from [the AWS Well-Architected documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/reliability-pillar/plan-for-disaster-recovery-dr.html):

> Recovery Time Objective (RTO) is ...the maximum acceptable delay between the interruption of service and restoration of service. This determines what is considered an acceptable time window when service is unavailable.
>
> Recovery Point Objective (RPO) is ... the maximum acceptable amount of time since the last data recovery point. This determines what is considered an acceptable loss of data between the last recovery point and the interruption of service.

The architecture or features determine what RPO and RTO are possible.  For a platform as a service, you do not define the implementation. If you pay for near zero RTO and RPO, then I'd expect something more than a single instance for HA and backup/restore for DR.

The following link might help explain some of this.  It's a complex subject.  The complexity can be a risk for RTO and RPO.  For example, our first SQL cluster did not failover correctly because some resources where not configured correctly as cluster resources...we lost a 9 for that.  I like this link because of the image that shows the feature relation to RTO and RPO - copied here.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/an-overview-of-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-solutions/ba-p/370479

[image: Chart showing the relationship of SQL feature to RTO and RPO]

The following link indicates the Azure instance or database has a 12h and 1h RTO and RPO, respectively, using geo restore.  You can use auto failover to improve this to 1h and 5s.  It's all very vendor specific.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/business-continuity-high-availability-disaster-recover-hadr-overview?view=azuresql

This link shows that paying more allows the use of features and resources that provide a better RTO and RPO.  I would expect "Hyperscale service tier zone redundant availability" to drain the wallet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/high-availability-sla?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell

If doing it yourself, the feature selection is not enough.  Having an old SAN go down for 3 days (yes) can be a real show stopper, no matter what features are used.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - what are "RTO" and "RPO"? What exactly will someone do to reduce them if you give them more money?

Comment: @IMSop I updated the post to include a link for RTO and RPO.  Some will claim RTO and RPO no longer applies.  For one service, I could not find what they meant by this and have no idea what the SLA (elastic?) might really be.  There's a big difference between designing for zero RTO and RPO and what an SLA will promise.  For example, we wanted four 9's for a SQL server 2008, so we built a cluster.  I still joke about getting four 8's instead.

Comment: I've edited those definitions into the text itself (with attribution) ... but I still don't see how this answers the question. You're basically saying "the fancy name for that 30 minutes is the RPO", but you don't actually say whether a 30 minute RPO is normal, and why. You say that a lower RPO "costs money", but you don't say anything about what you would be spending that money *on*. Is it just "pay Microsoft more money to unlock better features"? Is it "configuring for lower RPO takes a lot of expertise so you need to hire a contractor"?